# Login Control in ASP.NET 4

Tags: authentication

I'm using Login Control form in ASP.NET and after successful login would like to track the username to give welcome greeting and so on. Also, if any user tried to directly go to a random page without passing the authentication, then I would like to raise an error page. I tried various methods with Membership Control to retrieve the username but I'am getting errors. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

There are two controls for this task. LoginName gives you the current logged in user name and the other is LoginStatus which gives you the current status whether user is logged in successfully or not.

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
{
    Response.Redirect("your_redirecting_url");
}
```